# I get a 500 page instead of a ResponseStatus from exceptions within ServiceStack Service

Tags: servicestack

Using ServiceStack 4.0.33 and given the following simplified DTOs...

```cs
[Route("/products")]
[Route("/products/{Id}")]    
public class Product : IReturn<ProductResponse>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ProductResponse
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

with the following simplified service...

```cs
public class ProductService : Service
{
    public object Post(Product product)
    {
        Db.Insert<Product>(product);
        return new ProductResponse() { Product = product };
    }
}
```

and calling it via this in my `ProductsController`

```cs
using (var productService = ResolveService<ProductService>())
{
    var result = productService.Post(product);
    if (result.IsErrorResponse())
        return View(product);
    else
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

If I try to post a new Product with an intentional duplicate primary key, I get a 500 error HTML-style page instead of the `ResponseStatus` getting populated and returned...

[image]

I've seen lots of different StackOverflow posts about different reasons that `ResponseStatus` won't get populated, but I've tried several things to no avail. Am I missing something (hopefully simple)?

Comment: How are you calling this service on the client? and what is the error in the HTML page?

Comment: @mythz Edited to show how I'm calling and the error on the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where do you define the behavior that a duplicate key would be handled differently than HTTP 500. What other response would you expect? ResponseStatus can contain HTTP 500 which merely indicates a server-side error.

You have to specifically define that you want to handle the error differently and if so what type of error you want (which error code, which message) as explained [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling).

For instance:

```
public object Get(User request) 
{
    throw HttpError.NotFound("User {0} does not exist".Fmt(request.Name));
}
```

Check out the ServiceStack tutorial for more.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to handle it differently. I thought the nature of the auto-error-handling would wrap up the 500 in the `ResponseStatus`, which it does not seem to do.

Answer (score 0):

The error page you're getting is a **custom ASP.NET Error page** which hijacks any custom 500 HTTP error responses returned by your ASP.NET web application.

It can be disabled with:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

Here's another [alternative of disabling IIS errors](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Apr/29/IIS-7-Error-Pages-taking-over-500-Errors) by setting `TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true` which in ServiceStack can be set with:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
{
    ((HttpResponse)res.OriginalResponse).TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
});
```

Comment: I double-checked and verified that it is already `Off` in my web.config. For kicks, I also added `<customErrors mode="Off" />` inside the `<location path="api">` section as well. Lastly, I remembered I'm actually on 4.0.34 via MyGet because of the `LoadSelect` issue we talked about a few weeks ago.

Comment: @robertmiles3 the issue is definitely preventing IIS/ASP.NET errors from hijacking the request, [try also adding](http://chuchuva.com/pavel/2010/08/how-to-enable-detailed-error-information-for-iis-and-asp-net/) `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>`.

Comment: No go so far. Sorry. Hate to keep bugging. Obviously I can handle it explicitly with try/catch but it'd be awesome to know what's up.

Comment: @robertmiles3 no idea why it's not working for you as that's all I've ever had to do, I've added another link an example of disabling it in code.

Comment: Maybe you can see it too. I started my project based off your ServiceStack.Tests.Mvc solution. So, I just re-pulled that and tweaked it real fast for my setup. Run this and go to the About page which I have doing the work as a test. See if it does it for you too. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/492034/Test-master.zip